# Successfully complete 5 out of 6 free throws

Tags: probability

The probability that Abbas successfully completes a free throw in a basketball game is **0.7**.  Suppose that Abbas attempts **6** free throws in one game and that the outcomes of the free throws are independent. What is the probability that Abbas will successfully complete at least **5** free throws?

When trying to solve this problem, I did **(0.7)^5** = **0.1681**, but the answer is **0.4202**.

How would I get **0.4202**?

EDIT:
I now tried **(6!/5!) x (0.7)^5 x 0.3** = **0.3025**, still cannot get the answer.

SECOND EDIT: 
I think I have finally got it! **(6!/6! x (0.7)^6 x (0.3)^0** = **0.1176**

Then, **0.3025 + 0.1176 = 0.4201** ! I know I am off by 0.0001, but is my answer and work still correct? Thanks!

Comment: That only counts the probability that Abbas hits the first five free throws.

Comment: You need to use a different criteria than getting throw 1 to 5 to succeed.

Comment: Hint: how many ways can you choose at least 5 out of 6?

Comment: Hint for after edit: It is also possible that Abbas completes all 6 of the throws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 5 successful throws ($s$) out of 6, then you have one fail ($f$).

The throws can be arranged in 6 ways.

$sssssf$

$ssssfs$

$sssfss$

$ssfsss$

$sfssss$

$fsssss$

And the probability for one of the ways is $0.7^5\cdot 0.3^1$

You have to take into account, that one throw must fail.

Therefore the probability for 5 successful throws is $P(X=5)=6\cdot 0.7^5\cdot 0.3^1$

And the probability for 6 successful throws is $P(X=6)=0.7^6$. These successful throws can be arranged only in one way: $ssssss$

Therefore $P(X\geq 5)=P(X=5)+P(X=6)=6\cdot 0.7^5\cdot 0.3^1+0.7^6=0.42$.

For this kind of problems the [Binominal dstribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) can be used.

Comment: Your´re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need $$p(X\geq5|X\sim \operatorname{Bin}(6,0.7))$$
$$=p(X=5\cup6)=\binom 65 0.7^5\times0.3+0.7^6$$
$$=0.420175$$